# Multiplicity constraint violated Error while loading entity

Tags: entity-framework-6, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've seen this question been asked number of times but each has its own scenario and i couldn't find solution.

> I wanted to add a table that holds a survey data, and each `SURVEY` belongs to a `SITE`.

I tried adding a child table `Site_Survey` such that if forms One-to-Zero_or_One relationship to an exiting table `Site_Report`.

[image]

I'm using EF-6, Code first, with FluentApi for mapping. Following is how I've defined the Entities

*Site_Survey*

```
public class Site_Survey
    {
        // Scalar Properties
        public int site_survey_id { get; set; }
        // ..other properties removed for brevity


        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual Site_Report Site_Report { get; set; }
    }
```

*Site_Report*

```
public class Site_Report
    {
        public Site_Report()
        {
            this.Report_Assets = new HashSet<Report_Asset>();
            this.Site_Survey = new Site_Survey();
        }

        // Scalar Properties
        public int site_report_id { get; set; }
        // ..other properties removed for brevity

        // Navigation Properties
        // Site_Report one-to-zero_or_one Site_Survey
        public virtual Site_Survey Site_Survey { get; set; }
    }
```

*Mapping*

```
public class Site_SurveyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Site_Survey>
    {
        public Site_SurveyMap()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.site_survey_id);
        }
    }

public class Site_ReportMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Site_Report>
    {
        public Site_ReportMap()
        {
            HasKey(one => one.site_report_id);

            // mapping for Site_Report one-to-zero_or_one Site_Survey
            HasOptional(o => o.Site_Survey)         // Mark Site_Survey property optional in Site_Report entity
            .WithRequired(o => o.Site_Report)       // Mark Site_Report property as required in Site_Survey entity. 
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);             // i.e. Cannot save Site_Survey without Site_Report
        }
    }
```

Im initialising Site_Survey inside Site_Report constructor so that every new Site_Report would have at most one survey. For old existing sites having no records in Survey table i'm adding code logic and populate them when necessary.

**Problem**

From DbContext, whilst loading the `Site_Survey` object on its own, I successfully get correct survey record

```
Site_Survey model = ctx.Site_Survey.Where(i => i.site_survey_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

But if I try to include Site_Report Entity in the context, it throws the error.

```
Site_Survey model = ctx.Site_Survey.Include(i => i.Site_Report).Where(i => i.site_survey_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

And vice versa if try loading Site_Report and include Site_Survey.

**Error**

> "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Site_Report_Site_Survey_Target' of the relationship 'StevensCalcertPortal.DBAccessLayer.Site_Report_Site_Survey' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1."

The fact that it actually is 1-0..1 relationship, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help reading this article [Entity framework and Table splitting with Code First](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/08/28/entity-framework-and-table-splitting-with-code-first/). Following changes actually addressed my issue.

Keeping the `Site_Report` constructor as it was and using a separate static method `CreateEntity()` for generating objects. Also changing constructor's visibility to protected to force the use of static method where `new Site_Report();` was needed in the code.

```
public class Site_Report
    {
        public static Site_Report CreateEntity()
        {
            return new Site_Report()
            {
                Site_Survey = new Site_Survey()
            };
        }

        protected Site_Report()
        {
            this.Report_Assets = new HashSet<Report_Asset>();
            // this.Site_Survey = new Site_Survey();
        }
    }
```

Basically error happens if you initialise Site_Survey in constructor `this.Site_Survey = new Site_Survey();`.

Inside EF after issuing query to the database, when construct an instance of `Site_Report`, it got the `Site_Survey` already populated with an ID of 0 and EF complains because it got different ID from the database, so what EF thinking that `Site_Report`refers to two distinct `Site_Survey` when the relation is 1:1 (they should share the very same id).